# What is the best way to store multiple points (float, float)?

Tags: java, arrays, memory-management, points

I am new to Java and I need to store a big array of points (x, y float coordinates). Which of the options is better for storing in a big array (uses less memory)?

Point class:

```
// It`s in the same file as my main class

class Point {
    public float x;
    public float y;
    
    public Point(float x, float y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

or an array of arrays:

```
float[] point = { 0.0f, 0.0f };
float[][] positions = { //Multiple Pointes here\\ };
```

Comment: How many elements do you consider "big?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cheapest, in terms of memory, is probably to use a one-dimensional array (this may change once Java gets value objects) of size 2N where N is the number of points, where x is stored at 2n and y at 2n+1 (0 <= n < N).

In other words:

```
public class Points {

  private final float[] points;

  public Points(int size) {
    points = new float[2 * size];
  }

  public float getX(int index) {
    return points[2 * index];
  }

  public void setX(int index, float value) {
    points[2 * index] = value;
  }

  public float getY(int index) {
    return points[2 * index + 1];
  }

  public void setY(int index, float value) {
    points[2 * index + 1] = value;
  }
}
```

However, if you need to handle points individually, then using a `Point` class is better. It will have slight less overhead compare to using a two-dimensional array (IIRC, 16 bytes for `Point` vs 24 bytes for a `float[2]` per point), but also provides a better abstraction.

Comment: @Andreas The overhead of an array is 12 bytes. A single array of 2N float is 12 + 2N * 4 + 4 bytes (the last 4 is the padding to achieve multiples of 8 bytes). If we have an array of Point objects, the size is 12 + N * ((8 + 2 * 4) + 4 + 4) + 4 bytes (or 16 + N * 24 bytes). If we use a 2D array of floats, the size is 12 + N * ((12 + 2 * 4 + 4) + 4 + 4) + 4 bytes (or 16 + N * 32 bytes); those '+ 4 + 4' are 4 bytes for object/array reference and 4 bytes padding (or 8 bytes object/array reference without compressed OOPS).

Comment: I shouldn't have included 4 bytes of padding for each object reference in my calculation, but I think the rest still holds.

Comment: **```However, if you need to handle points individually```** what do you mean handle points individually?

Comment: It looks like a good solution and I will need to read the pointes in a for loop so I can just jump 2 and get the point, I think I will use this. Thank you

Comment: @user15329314 The advantage of using something like `Point` (or a `float[][]`), is that you can pass individual points (either a `Point` or a `float[2]`) around. With the single one-dimensional array solution that is no longer possible (or you need to temporarily put the (x, y) in a `Point` or `float[2]` to pass it elsewhere, but that has issues with mutability and of course some extra overhead). And of course a `Point` has advantages that it can have additional operations defined next to the data.

Answer (score 0):

An object has an overhead. If the only thing you're concerned about is memory consumption, a two dimensional array of primitive `float`s would be "cheaper".

Comment: I disagree. An array is an object too, and it has an overhead with having to store the array length, so it uses more memory. The overhead of an extra class is one-time, as the class definition is loaded for the first time. After that there is no extra overhead, while an array has storage overhead on every instance used.

Comment: Yes, echo to @Mureinik. Even geospatial data libraries like GeoJSON (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON) uses multidimensional float array to represents coordinates.

Comment: @Lovababu Your comment is off-point (irrelevant), since you're talking about how the information is serialized to JSON, but this question is about how the data is best stored in Java data structures.

Comment: @Andreas my intention here is to show how framework/libraries are storing the geospatial data.